# Is there a replacement for this syntax?

Tags: python, pandas, weekday

with the new update on pandas I can't use this function that I used on on Datacamp learning course - (DAYOFWEEK doesn't exist anymore)

```
days_of_week = pd.get_dummies(dataframe.index.dayofweek,
                          prefix='weekday',
                          drop_first=True)
```

How can I change the syntax of my 'formula' to get the same results?

Sorry about the silly question but spent a lot of time here and I'm stuck...

Thanks in advance!

already tried just using the dataframe with index but doesn't get the days of the week on the get dummies\

used datetimeindex but messing up on the formulation as well

```
`days_of_week = pd.get_dummies(dataframe.index.dayofweek, prefix='weekday', drop_first=True)`
```

the dataframe is fairly big and need the outputs to get me the weekdays because I'm dealing with stock prices

Comment: Guessing it isn't a datetime Index. Do this first: `pd.to_datetime(dataframe.index, errors='coerce').dayofweek`

Comment: [pd.to_datetime(dataframe.index, errors='coerce').dayofweek] worked perfectly!! thanks a lot @coldspeed

Answer (score 0):

Try `weekday` instead of `dayofweek`.

So

```
days_of_week = pd.get_dummies(dataframe.index.weekday,
                          prefix='weekday',
                          drop_first=True)
```

See docs below:

[pandas.Series.dt.weekday](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html#pandas.Series.dt.weekday)

Comment: [pd.to_datetime(dataframe.index, errors='coerce').dayofweek] worked but will check that as well, thanks Bryce!!

Comment: @ThiagoAV this also needs the index to be date time which yours is not, this too will not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @coldspeed that's exactly what happened... keeping the other method you suggested! thanks again

Comment: Cool @ThiagoAV if you are satisfied with the answer, please accept or up-vote :)